# Preventing viewing css and js files using direct url

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess

I am trying to prevent the direct access to my website resources using htaccess.My website is orlandojoes.co.uk/clouds which is a subfolder.But if i enter `orlandojoes.co.uk/clouds/css/style.css` in the address bar i can see them.But i want to prevent seeking them and redirect to index.html.

## I am trying:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?orlandojoes.co.uk\.ltd [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?orlandojoes.co.uk\.ltd.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|js|txt|css)$ /HeyManYouHaveComeToAwrongPlace;) [L]
```

But it blocks all.Even in index.html page show only markups not with stylings.
What can be a solve?

Comment: Why do you want to block direct access? Even if you succeed, the user can still view the files after loading whichever of your html pages use those resources.

Comment: this has nothing to do with html css or javascript

Comment: looking at the ReqriteCond lines, you'd block requests unless they came from `www.orlandojoes?co?uk.ltd` - where ? is any character - I think you need to check the RewriteCond syntax

Comment: @nnnnnn its not a problm if they can see which resources i am using... such as i am using `style.css` but i want them not to access into the file

Comment: if, as you say, you don't want them to access the file then you've done that. However, visitors MUST access the file as part of the page - and once it's loaded in the page, anyone with 2 working neurons can see your super special code/css/images

Comment: Do you have the URL correct?  It ends with .ltd?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes visitors MUST have access .But if visitors select `view page source` and page source page when they click a link such as `www.orlandojoes.co.uk/clouds/css/style.css` they can see the css file contains.I want t prevent that

Comment: your rewritecond isn't escaping the '.' in the host name, and has `ltd` as part of the referer it's trying to match - so, your index.html will fail to get your css js etc too - basically your rewriteCond is ensuring nothing can read the css js etc

Comment: There is *no way* to prevent the user seeing the contents of your css file once the browser has loaded an html page that uses that css file.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Answer: **You cannot do that**.

If you want the browser to apply `CSS` to your webpage and execute `JavaScript`, then you cannot prevent it from the users.

If you manage to **block the `CSS` and `JS`** files, then **how will the browser access them?**

The most you can do is **[minify](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=minify)** or **[uglify](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=uglify)**, which will just make it difficult (not impossible) to view your `CSS` and `JavaScript`.